# Wordpress: Ajax call doesn't work (Error 400 Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

in simple words: Ajax is called from Javascript file, but php function doesn't 'hear' the call.
In my case PHP and Javascript are in separate files. I proved that they are loaded correct in functions.php by:

```
function LoadScriptsOnSpecificPages(){
    global $wp_query;
    $page_id = intval($wp_query->queried_object->ID);
    
    // Page ID 2614 = Buchung Auswahl Raum, Page ID 2654 = Buchung abschließen
    if (($page_id = 2614) or ($page_id = 2654)) {
        include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom/booking.php';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/booking.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'LoadScriptsOnSpecificPages');
```

In "booking.php" at the top:

```
//Define AJAX URL and requests
function define_ajax_url() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'define_ajax_url');

// Action hooks that work with the WordPress AJAX functionality
// wp_ajax_nopriv_ action Hooks bewirken, dass der Ajax-Request auch bei Website-Besuchern läuft,
// die nicht eingeloggt sind.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_AjaxSessionIDerzeugen', 'AjaxSessionIDerzeugen' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_AjaxSessionIDerzeugen', 'AjaxSessionIDerzeugen' );
```

Problem: Also in the file "booking.php" the function that should be called, but unfortunately is never called:

```
// Ajax Session ID erzeugen
function AjaxSessionIDerzeugen() {
    $ip_adresse = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    
    // $_REQUEST contains the data sent via AJAX from the Javascript call
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $session_id = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
        $strsql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_buchungen (session_id) VALUES session_id= '%s'",$session_id);
        $wpdb->query($strsql);

        // Callback
        callback:
        $arr = array();
        $arr['pruefergebnis'] = "ok";
        $arr['session_id'] = $session_id;

        $antwort_json = json_encode($arr);
        echo $antwort_json;
    }
    // Always die in functions echoing AJAX content
   die();
}
```

In the file "booking.js" there is the Ajax-Call that doesn't work.
Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

```
if ((session_id == '') || (session_id == null)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
                data: {
                    'action':'AjaxSessionIDerzeugen', // PHP function
                },
    
                // Callback
                success:function(antwort) {
                    let object = JSON.parse(antwort);
                    pruefergebnis = object.pruefergebnis;
    
                    if (pruefergebnis == 'ok') {
                        session_id = object.session_id;
                        document.cookie = "session_id=" + session_id + "; expires=3600000; path=/";
                    } else {
                        window.alert(pruefergebnis);
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    window.alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        }
```

I checked the network tab for the Ajax URL. It seems to be ok. Am I right?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The admin-ajax URL is available on admin side, for the front end you need to define it, I correct some small error and tested on my local it is working

```
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl, //you need to point to correct URL if you are working on frontend
                data: {
                    action:'AjaxSessionIDerzeugen', // PHP function
                },
    
                // Callback
                success:function(antwort) {
                    let object = JSON.parse(antwort);
                    pruefergebnis = object.pruefergebnis;
    
                    if (pruefergebnis == 'ok') {
                        session_id = object.session_id;
                        document.cookie = "session_id=" + session_id + "; expires=3600000; path=/";
                    } else {
                        window.alert(pruefergebnis);
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    window.alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how do I find out the correct Ajax url?

Comment: It would be best if you localized correctly also you can hardcode but it will be a headache for you while changing the domain etc.
The URL is
https://yourwebsiteurl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: I checked out: ajaxurl is available in the frontend by default. It points exactly to the URL you specified. I also replaced it by the absolute path, which is in my case: 'http://localhost/.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'. It's still not working.

Comment: Where did you put the code? In which directory? In the directory of the child-theme or Plugins or anywhere else? My code (.js and .php files) is in the sub-directory "custom" of the child-theme. Maybe this is the reason that it doesn't work.

Comment: No it is not the reason, if you point out the URL then check the network tab in browser you will get the response

Comment: @AliUsman I checked the network tab. It seems to be ok. Can you please have a look at the screenshot I added above? Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: No, it's not okay, your request is returning the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work was, that - in functions.php of the theme - I restricted the loading of files booking.php and booking.js to the pages where I need it (by Page ID). This was a mistake.
My code in the functions.php that works now is:

```
include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom/booking.php';

function LoadScript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/booking.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'LoadScript');
```